# What are the exact requirements for the rep cap hat?

Tags: support, winterbash

The description for the Rep Cap hat says that to get it I need to "Hit the reputation cap (200 in one day)".

I hit 207 yesterday, with 30 of that being for accepted answers and 2 for an answer I accepted on one of my questions, and the UTC day rolled over 6 hours ago, but I still don't have the hat.

I'd guessed that the rep check for this hat would be similar to the Mortarboard and Legendary badges, so the +2 for accepting an answer wouldn't count towards it, but +15 for each accepted answer would. Is that right?

If yes, why am I missing a hat? If no, what are the actual requirements? (And the hat description might need an update in the latter case.)

Comment: For future reference, you don't need the day to roll over. I got the Rep Cap hat soon after I reached 200 rep via upvotes.

Comment: @Raven Ahh, upvotes only then? Good to know (and somewhat unfortunate). Thanks. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it yesterday, but I exceeded the reputation cap, which I'm pretty sure is the thing that matters. Other users who also received the hat exceeded the reputation cap as well:

- [agent86](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/13845/agent86?tab=reputation)
- [yx.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/3917/yx?tab=reputation)
- [Raven Dreamer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/336/raven-dreamer?tab=reputation)
- [Jeff Mercado](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/8995/jeff-mercado?tab=reputation)

And you can only hit the reputation cap via up-votes on non-Community Wiki posts: [accepts and bounties don't count towards your reputation cap](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation):

> You can earn a maximum of 200 reputation per day. Please note that votes for posts marked “community wiki” do not generate any reputation, while accepted answers and bounty awards are not subject to the daily reputation limit.

The fact that the [Mortarboard, Epic, and Legendary badges count accepts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions/68258#68258) is odd (and news to me), but I'm not sure if the hat is supposed to match them, the badges are wrong (they should be counting the number of times you hit the rep cap, not hit some arbitrary rep limit), or if the hat is not supposed to be pegged to the badges.

If it's the latter (hat and badges aren't linked), the hat description should probably just remove the parenthetical clarification, as it's misleading particularly when compared to the badges with similar descriptions.